# Replacing Strings Containing $ Characters

Tags: powershell, replace, associative-array, powershell-3.0

I'm trying to develop a script that will replace certain tokens in the input text with new test strings.  With the help of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7461936/powershell-replacing-in-strings-using-a-hashtable), I've developed the following:

```
$repl = @{}
$repl.add('SVN',"myworkspace\BRANCH71")
$repl.add('REL',"72")

$string = 'C:\users\rojomoke\filesREL\SVN\blah.txt'
foreach ($h in $repl.getenumerator())
{
    write-host "Line: $($h.name): $($h.value)"
    $string = $string -replace "$($h.name)","$($h.value)"
    write-host $string
}
```

which produces the required `C:\users\rojomoke\files72\myworkspace\BRANCH71\blah.txt`.

However, it all goes to sh^H^Hpieces when I try to use tokens that are marked by starting with a `$` sign.  If in the above example I use tokens `$REL` and `$SVN`, then no substitution takes place, and `$string` remains as `C:\users\rojomoke\files$REL\$SVN\blah.txt`.

I assume I'm running afoul of a regexp expansion or something, but I can't see how.  Is it possible to quote the dollar sign so that this works properly?

I'm using Powershell version 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$repl = @{}
$repl.add('\$SVN',"myworkspace\BRANCH71")
$repl.add('\$REL',"72")

$string = 'C:\users\rojomoke\files$REL\$SVN\blah.txt'
foreach ($h in $repl.getenumerator()) {
    write-host "Line: $($h.name): $($h.value)"
    $string = $string -replace "$($h.name)","$($h.value)"
    write-host $string
}
```

Works because in regex you have to escape the `$` with the regex escape character `\`.

Answer (score 1):

The `-replace` operator uses regular expression matches. The `$`character has a special meaning in regular expressions ("end of string"), as do some other characters. To avoid this you must escape these characters in the search string:

```
$srch = [regex]::Escape('$SVN')
$repl = 'myworkspace\BRANCH71'

$string = 'C:\users\rojomoke\filesREL\$SVN\blah.txt'

$string -replace $srch, $repl
```

However, if you use variable-like syntax anyway, why don't you just use variables?

```
$repl = @{
  'SVN' = 'myworkspace\BRANCH71'
  'REL' = '72'
}

$repl.GetEnumerator() | % { New-Variable -Name $_.Name -Value $_.Value }

$string = "C:\users\rojomoke\files$REL\$SVN\blah.txt"
```

If you need to define `$string` before the nested variables are defined, you can define the string with single quotes and evaluate it at a later point in time:

```
$repl = @{
  'SVN' = 'myworkspace\BRANCH71'
  'REL' = '72'
}

$repl.GetEnumerator() | % { New-Variable -Name $_.Name -Value $_.Value }

$string = 'C:\users\rojomoke\files$REL\$SVN\blah.txt'

$expandedString = $ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString($string)
```

Answer (score 1):

`-replace` treats the first argument as a Regular Expression pattern. In regex,  `$` is a special character denoting the last character position ("end") of a string. Therefore, when trying to match the literal character `$` in a string, you need to escape it.

You can use [`[regex]::Escape($pattern)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape(v=vs.110).aspx) for this:

```
$repl = @{}
$repl.add([regex]::Escape('$SVN'),"myworkspace\BRANCH71")
$repl.add([regex]::Escape('$REL'),"72")
```